# Is my Inverse z-transform solution method accurate?

Tags: signal, z-transform

**The question is as follows:**
[image]

**The book answer is as follows:**
[image]

**However, my approach is as shown below I even cross checked my partial fraction and it was correct.**
[image]

**Please tell me where is my mistake?**

---

---

### *****Ok. Below is my revised trial after Mr. Any pointed where was my mistake. Kindly review my answer and advise me where is my mistake.*****

[image]

I used the z transform property of shifting:
[image]

Comment: @user215805 don't waste my time. Don't even read my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stopped at what appears to be your first mistake: -

[image]

Comment: Ok how would you solve it? just give me a hint!

Comment: I have done it in a different way can I edit my question or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @OMAR did you get the right answer this time?

Comment: Not sure. But I want to show you. can i add it here in my question? or I should ask a new one. I want to be sure

Comment: I will just have to make a new question I think.

Comment: If you have an imgur account you could post a picture there and link it in a comment. Or, if you think you have a correct answer, then you could post it as an answer. There are circumstances where adding to questions (following details in an answer) confuses things but, if you make it clear that you are adding something following my answer then it should be OK. There's absolutely no guarantee that I'll be able to offer any help though and, you may have to raise a new question. Having said that, I'm quite good with PF stuff.

Comment: Great I made a question new one. However, here is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXeyx.jpg

Comment: What does PF stuff mean?

Comment: PF = partial fractions

Comment: @OMAR I believe that you should divide by an extra z in order to get the formula with the correct powers in the numerator and denominator for it to work correctly. Maybe note this at the bottom of page 2 [source](https://courses.media.mit.edu/2007fall/mas160/zII.pdf). It says that the formula should contain only nonpositive or nonnegative powers of z. I'm a bit out of my league here!!!

Comment: I read it. If you notice my edited answer is a nonpositive one i.e. it's not mixed. Am I right?

Comment: @OMAR Your answer is correct, it's the same as (D). It's just another way of expressing the partial fraction expansion. If you don't believe it, check numerically for \$n = 0, 1, 2, ... \$

Comment: I'm out of my depth here. I can see why the formal answer divided by an extra z and I think it's to do with the page 2 source information I gave but, I'm not gifted enough to give you sound reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. Answer (D) is also correct, but expressed in a different partial fraction expansion format.

This can be checked by letting \$\small n=\{0, 1, 2, 3\: ...\}\$ in answer (D), and in your solutions, and also by doing the long division: \$\large\frac{5z+2}{z^2-5z+4}\$.

These will all produce the sequence \$\small x[n]=\{0, 5, 27, 115, ...\}\$

A clever question.

Comment: Are you saying that (-7/3)*u(k-1) = 0.5*δ(k) + (-7/3)*u(k)?

Comment: No, I'm saying \$\small (1/2)\delta \ [n]-(7/3)u[n]+(11/6)(4)^n u[n]=(22/3)(4)^n u[n]-(7/3)u[n]=(5z+2)\div (z^2 -5z+4)\$

Comment: For the sake of argument, both sides have −(7/3)u[n] thus they cancel eachother out, the remaining will becomes (1/2)δ [n] + (11/6)(4)^n*u[n] = (22/3)(4)^n*u[n]. Which is clearly not!